# How can I get the docker whale in my terminal?

Tags: docker

I see some folks have the docker whale [in asci art] when they start a new terminal window. How can I do that? Even when not using docker

Comment: Isn't it a part of boot2docker? is [this the one](https://github.com/abrkn/boot2docker/blob/036f5ff903350be9132acde88a0fc8e137ae8690/rootfs/isolinux/boot.msg)?

Comment: They are probably running the cowsay program in bashrc. There are instruction to install the command on your machine on https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/whalesay/ (while this is a Dockerfile, you can run the commands mentioned there on your local machine and it should work)

Comment: This is definitely the whalesay image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Way:

```
$ echo $'\n                  ##        .\n            ## ## ##       ==\n         ## ## ## ##      ===\n     /""""""""""""""""\___/ ===\n~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~ ~ /  ===-- ~~~\n     \______ o          __/\n       \    \        __/\n        \____\______/\n'

                  ##        .
            ## ## ##       ==
         ## ## ## ##      ===
     /""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~ ~ /  ===-- ~~~
     \______ o          __/
       \    \        __/
        \____\______/
```

A more maintainable or copyable and maintainable version might be

```
echo $'\n' \
$'                  ##        .\n' \
$'            ## ## ##       ==\n' \
$'         ## ## ## ##      ===\n' \
$'     /""""""""""""""""\___/ ===\n' \
$'~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~ ~ /  ===-- ~~~\n' \
$'     \______ o          __/\n' \
$'       \    \        __/\n' \
$'        \____\______/\n'
```